# iOS crash when using MOKO resource library

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform

I had this issue couple of days ago that i couldn't actually resolve with MOKO resource library, the `stringResource` is used in Compose multiplatform, the app run with no issues on android but on iOS it has a bug that i couldn't debug, is there might be any libraries that i could use for debugging or anyone can help with this problem that would be great:

Moko resource version : `0.23.0`,

kotlin version : `1.9.21` and compose version `1.5.4`.

the MR is generated correctly and works fine on android what could be the issue here ?

```
Uncaught Kotlin exception: kotlin.native.internal.FileFailedToInitializeException: There was an error during file or class initialization
    at 0   BaridiApp                           0x104e91643        kfun:kotlin.Error#<init>(kotlin.String?;kotlin.Throwable?){} + 143 
    at 1   BaridiApp                           0x104ec3637        kfun:kotlin.native.internal.FileFailedToInitializeException#<init>(kotlin.String?;kotlin.Throwable?){} + 143 
    at 2   BaridiApp                           0x104ec2893        ThrowFileFailedToInitializeException + 275 
    at 3   BaridiApp                           0x104ffbc03        CallInitGlobalPossiblyLock + 759 
    at 4   BaridiApp                           0x10462ee53        kfun:com.mahmoud.talaa.SharedRes.strings#<get-$instance>#static(){}com.mahmoud.talaa.SharedRes.strings + 75 
    at 5   BaridiApp                           0x104630927        kfun:ComposableSingletons$AppKt.<init>$lambda$0#internal + 431 
    at 6   BaridiApp                           0x104630ea7        kfun:ComposableSingletons$AppKt.$<init>$lambda$0$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$1.invoke#internal + 95 
    at 7   BaridiApp                           0x104630f5b        kfun:ComposableSingletons$AppKt.$<init>$lambda$0$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$1.$<bridge-UNNNB>invoke(androidx.compose.runtime.Composer;kotlin.Int){}#internal + 159 
    at 8   BaridiApp                           0x104f8ecd7        kfun:kotlin.Function2#invoke(1:0;1:1){}1:2-trampoline + 115 
    at 9   BaridiApp                           0x1050e52f3        kfun:androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl#invoke(androidx.compose.runtime.Composer;kotlin.Int){}kotlin.Any? + 587 
    at 10  BaridiApp                           0x1050f2cc3        kfun:androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl#$<bridge-NNNNB>invoke(androidx.compose.runtime.Composer;kotlin.Int){}kotlin.Any?(androidx.compose.runtime.Composer;kotlin.Any?){}kotlin.Any? + 163 
    at 11  BaridiApp                           0x104f8ecd7        kfun:kotlin.Function2#invoke(1:0;1:1){}1:2-trampoline + 115 
    at 12  BaridiApp                           0x1053c7b77        kfun:androidx.compose.material.Surface$lambda$2#internal + 4799 
    at 13  BaridiApp                           0x1053c800f        kfun:androidx.compose.material.$Surface$lambda$2$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$0.invoke#internal + 155 
    at 14  BaridiApp                           0x1053c8263        kfun:androidx.compose.material.$Surface$lambda$2$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$0.$<bridge-UNNNB>invoke
```

Comment: the problem is that whenever building the iOS app, removing this line from app level build.gradle.kts  `androidMain { dependsOn(comminMain.get()) }` this resolved this issue, when building an android app put that again in the build.gradle.kts